# How to get data from State?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, reactjs-flux, immutable.js, react-router-redux

I am firing an action and trying to get data from the State but when I do it returns a weirdly complex Object instead of a string .

```
const autoPopulateCellnumber  = (getState) => {
const cell = getState().getIn(['answers','owner-contact-number'])
const type = types.AUTO_POPULATE_CELLNUMBER;
  return {
    type,
    payload: { cell } ,
  };
};
```

here **cell** becomes an Object map wwith these keys

["size", "_root", "__ownerID", "__hash", "__altered"]

*I can't copy and paste it here because its too big*

I wanted cell to be like "+2773 1234567"
[image]

Comment: If it's too big to copy & pasty, you might consider uploading an image of it!

Comment: how about extracting answers and owner-contact-number by destructuring them from state? `{ answers, owner-contact-number } = state;`

Comment: getState is not the state object , I also did try it that way but instead made my function take in 'state' and just said `state.getIn(['answers','owner-contact-number'])` but I still got the same answer

Comment: Can your try `console.log(cell.toJS())`

Comment: Hi we may be using vastly different approaches here how come you are not using . `getState().answers.owner-contact-number` . You can see I do something similar here https://github.com/zacck/ReactTODOSample/blob/master/app/actions/actions.jsx  on line  31.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Thanks , that seemed to make things clearer for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cells` is a `immutableMap` . You can convert it into a JS object by using 
`cells.toJS()` and then access any of the properties inside of it using `brackets or dot notation` like in aby other javascript object.

I hope that helps